Unable to canonicalize address 127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:2181 because it's not resolvable

2024-09-12 10:16:28.896  INFO 18540 --- [           main] o.a.d.c.d.DefaultApplicationDeployer     :  [DUBBO] use registry as config-center: <dubbo:config-center highestPriority="false" id="config-center-zookeeper-127.0.0.1-2181" address="zookeeper://127.0.0.1:2181" protocol="zookeeper" port="2181" parameters="{client=null}" />, dubbo version: 3.2.5, current host: 192.168.31.116
2024-09-12 10:16:29.106  WARN 18540 --- [127.0.0.1:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server 127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to canonicalize address 127.0.0.1/<unresolved>:2181 because it's not resolvable
        at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:65)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:41)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1001)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1060)

当我搭建dubbo环境时报错
When I build a dubbo environment, I get an error
dubbo：dubbo-admin-server-0.7.0
zookeeper：3.9.2
jdk：1.8
change the version of jkd, dubbo-admin and zk，but it didnt work

You are using Dubbo with ZooKeeper, and there could be an incompatibility between Dubbo 3.2.5 and the ZooKeeper version you are connecting to.
https://github.com/apache/dubbo?tab=readme-ov-file
in this link, dependency list of each Dubbo version is given, which they have tested and confirmed. Better to go with those version to ensure the compatibility.
Higher version of zk can cause these issues.chances are high..
